# Failing to load a JSON File on my server

Tags: php, json, header, file-get-contents, shared-hosting

first of all, my script:

```
<?php
$str = file_get_contents('https://externurl');

$json = json_decode($str, true); // 
echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

I am not aloud to share the link but it is a json file, which is ip protected. 
The Host of the JSON file whitelisted the IP of my domain.
When I execute the file on my server, I get an empty page. In the error logs I find this:

```
[10-Jun-2018 18:12:48 America/New_York] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://url): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized

 in /home/be/public_html/testtest/testing3.php on line 2
```

Then I checked with a not protected json file and I dont get this error. The IP is 100% whitelisted and is the IP of my domain.

Does it have something to do that I am on shared hosting? I am trying to solve this now for all day and read something about sending header because of the shared hosting, but I have no idea how. Am I on the right track?

Comment: `401 Unauthorized` im betting you provided the wrong IP

Comment: I did not. I double checked. Thats why I am asking, if it has something to do, that I am on shared hosting.

Comment: does `file_get_contents('https://www.google.com');` work?

Comment: returns an empty site and an empty error log.

Comment: your host may not have not enable the http wrappers, but the errors should be different, ask the host and try something like curl()

Comment: file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=google') returns the json. Thank you anyway. I will ask my host now, what it is about the ip adress. A second protected json file is also not working.

Comment: could you provide a curl example? I am not familiar with.

Comment: the manuals examples are the best http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php

Comment: `echo file_get_contents('http://www.whatsmyip.org/');` see if it agrees whit what you think your server IP is

Comment: Thank you smith, i already used minutes ago: $str = file_get_contents('https://api.ipify.org?format=json'); And it is not the IP adress of the FTP or the domain whois. crazy. But thank you for your time.

Comment: no reasons those 3 should match (especially on a shared host). live and learn :-) the external IP may not be static, so check that with the host.